# Can not run any UWP project at all

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio-2017 for Windows Form applications without problem. But no UWP project runs any more.

Downloaded sample UWP projects but they don't run any more. Even a simple HelloWorld app.

```
exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
'wup2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
'wup2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
'wup2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcomp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
'wup2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\BCP47Langs.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
'wup2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
onecoreuap\shell\coreapplication\application\lib\coreapplication.cpp(725)\twinapi.appcore.dll!00007FFB529B5D01: (caller: 00007FFB5294ECEE) FailFast(1) tid(11a4) 80070005 Access denied
    CallContext:[\AppRunOrActivateView] 
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB529B5D01 (twinapi.appcore.dll) in wup2.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

The program '[7516] wup2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Error message points here:

[image]

Comment: Another error, for other sample UWP program. What is wrong with twinapi.appcore.dll ??                                                                                                                       Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB529B5D01 (twinapi.appcore.dll) in SDKTemplate.exe: Fatal program exit requested.

Comment: Please don't post an image of an error message, especially not a link to some potentially shady image hosting site. Instead, copy the error message into the question as text.

Comment: Please see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060) and paste in the error message as @FeiXiang says.

Comment: have you disabled UAC? UWP apps require UAC

Comment: No, UAC is enabled in windows10. Any other parameter to change in VS or c# ?